# can I do isatty() without opening the file

Tags: linux, c

On Linux,

Is it possible to do the equivalent of `isatty(fd)` given a path, and without using `open()`?

I found that I cat `stat()` the path to determine that it is a character device.
Next, I can take the major and minor device numbers and check `/sys/dev/char/<major>:<minor>/subsystem` and see if it links to something ending in `/class/tty`.
This seems to works except for `/dev/pts/<number>` devices (which do not appear in `/sys/dev/char`).

Is there a more complete method?

Comment: mm, why? As far as I understand, one would usually use `isatty()` to check what an already open fd is connected to, e.g. `isatty(fileno(stdin))` to see if the program is running interactively. But if you're given a filename, what would the use case be? And why not just open the file, continue doing what ever it is you're supposed to do, and fail if you _then_ get an error?

Comment: @ilkkachu I used that in a lsof-like program to determine via `/proc/PID/fd/FD` if *another* process had open a terminal, and if I needed to proceed with all the heavy lifting needed to determine the actual device it referred to in order to list it together with other processes using it (no, the rdev major:minor aren't enough -- the files opened by `/dev/console`, `/dev/tty`, `/dev/tty0` may actually refer to the same device, despite being "different" device nodes; and even with `pidfd_getfd()` it's still gross and you don't want to do it for each and every open fd).

Comment: @ilkkachu and frankly I don't find such "appeals to the lack of imagination" as that from your comment above ... inspiring (to put it mildly)

Comment: @user499944, well, I was asking for the use-case, because often it clears up the context. What that use-case is, is up to your imagination, or lack of it, not mine.

Comment: @ilkkachu Why: sanity checking before doing an actual open.  Particularly since opens can do things like block unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `/proc/tty/drivers` instead of `/sys/class/tty`.

That won't be very robust, of course. Notice that `isatty()` works by actually calling an ioctl which is only supposed to work on terminals (`tcgetattr()` -> `ioctl(TCGETS)`). It doesn't guess from the file's flags or other metadata.

Comment: There are issues with a race condition, in the event a module is added or removed.  There are issues with the need to parse the file  (each time, to prevent a larger race).  Otherwise, this seems a good solution.   I hate to say it, but I could hardcode a lot of the stuff from there, and make autoconf tell me if I'm in Linux.